# When I import fileinput module, use the input method , it report AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'input'

Tags: python

The version of python is **2.7.13**.

The content of 3.txt is:

```
this is a river

that is a cloud

the world is beatiful
```

I write a python script:

```
import fileinput

def process(string):
    print 'Processing: ', string

for line in fileinput.input(r'E:\Python\3.txt'):
    process(line)
```

When I run this script , it report error:

```
====================== RESTART: E:\Python\fileinput.py ======================

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "E:\Python\fileinput.py", line 1, in <module>

  import fileinput

  File "E:\Python\fileinput.py", line 7, in <module>

  for line in fileinput.input(r'E:\Python\3.txt'):

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'input'

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What is the reason cause this problem ?

How can I slove this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don’t name your script “fileinput.py”. It conflicts with the library module of the same name.